# Creating Swift Properties

Tags: swift, dynamic, properties

I want to create a Swift property within a class or struct.  I think the code would be really clean and beautiful if I can make a accessible anywhere within the class and in other classes.  The problem I have is I want its type to be dynamic. Is this possible?

**Code**

```
class A {
    var property: Any
    init() {
        switch B {
        case 1:
             property: String = "Hello World"
        case 2:
             property: Int = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible, instead, you will need to think of generics, which can help to collect common behaviours across types. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 0):

`Any` is a legitimate type. But you are trying to do some sort of type redefinition. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public class A {
  public var someProperty: Any
  init(isString: Bool) {
    switch isString {
    case true:
      someProperty = "Hello World"
    case false:
      someProperty = 1
    }
  }
}

let foo = A(isString: true)
print(foo.someProperty)
let bar = A(isString: false)
print(bar.someProperty)
```

This produces:

```
Hello World
1
```

You can check type using `is`, the *type check operator*